# add extra parameter in ms sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a mssql query, in that query i would like to put 8 parameters, they are:

1. **table_primary_key** : primary key column name,
2. table_name : table name,
3. start_row : starting from this row,
4. limit_row : end row,
5. **column_name** : where column name,
6. **column_value** : where column name = column value,
7. sort_by : sort by column name.
8. **order** : ASC / DESC.

note: the bold one is the one i haven't implemented yet.

my current query is this :

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM ( 
       SELECT *, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY *sort_by*) as row
       FROM *table_name* 
       ) a
 WHERE row > *start_row* AND row <= *limit_row*
```

my question is how I add **table_primary_key**, **column_name**, **column_value**, **order** to my current query?

> my goal is make query display data from a table_name, start from
>   start_row until limit_row, where column_name = column_value. and the
>   data will be sort by sort_by and the order is according to order

if my question int clear enough please ask, thanks

Comment: Have a look on dynamic SQL and EXEC

Comment: What's the logic behind that? Please post some data and expected results.

Comment: @Shnugo thanks i'll look into it

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas logic for query im want to achieve?, i want query display data from a table_name, start from start_row until limit_row, where column_name = column_value. and the data will be sort by sort_by and the order is according to order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use dynamic sql  expression like this:

```
declare 
    @table_primary_key varchar(max) = 'ProjectID',
    @table_name varchar(max) = 'ProjectList',
    @start_row int = 10,
    @limit_row int = 20,
    @column_name varchar(max) = 'ProjectStatus',
    @column_value varchar(max) = '5',
    @sort_by varchar(max) = 'ProjectName',
    @order varchar(4) = 'ASC' -- 'DESC'

declare 
    @sql varchar(max) = ''

set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ( ' 
            + 'SELECT ' + @table_primary_key + ', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @sort_by + ' ' + @order + ') as row FROM ' + @table_name + ' WHERE ' + @column_name + ' = ''' + @column_value + ''') a' 
            + ' WHERE row > ' + cast(@start_row as varchar) + ' and row <= ' + cast(@limit_row as varchar)

exec ( @sql )
```

Or you can use stored procedure

```
create procedure dbo.GetResults
(
    @table_primary_key varchar(max),
    @table_name varchar(max),
    @start_row int,
    @limit_row int,
    @column_name varchar(max),
    @column_value varchar(max),
    @sort_by varchar(max),
    @order varchar(4)
)
as
begin   
    declare 
    @sql varchar(max) = ''

    set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ( ' 
            + 'SELECT ' + @table_primary_key + ', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @sort_by + ' ' + @order + ') as row FROM ' + @table_name + ' WHERE ' + @column_name + ' = ''' + @column_value + ''') a' 
            + ' WHERE row > ' + cast(@start_row as varchar) + ' and row <= ' + cast(@limit_row as varchar)

    exec ( @sql )
end
```

and then...

```
exec GetResults 'ProjectID', 'ProjectList', 10, 20, 'ProjectStatus', '5', 'ProjectName', 'ASC'
```

Comment: Thanks @JerzyG , but your query didnt include column name, and column value

Comment: could you please add column_name, and column_value to query?, thanks^^

Comment: I've modified the source for additional condition `@column_name = @column_value`. For numeric value type you should change `'''` to `'`.